# tablet is not changing from landscape to portrait and vice versa

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to test my application with  landscape to portrait but my tablet work only with landscabe and I don't know why ?

Comment: In certain tablets like my Nexus 7, the orientation can be locked. Check under Settings to see whether any such setting is preventing your tablet to change orientation (landscape <--> portrait). If other screens like the settings screen work and the app under test does not work, then it means that the app developer have constrained the orientation.

Comment: I made a reset of device and now the problem has been solved

Comment: @forsubhi If the problem is solved, add an answer to your question and accept it, so that other visitors know that you've solved the problem.

Comment: @Narayanan That looks more like an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a reset of the device and now the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

In certain tablets like my Nexus 7, the orientation can be locked as seen from one of Google search result:

[image]

Check under Settings to see whether any such setting is preventing your tablet to change orientation (landscape <--> portrait). This can also be achieved quickly with a drop down from top left corner of the display. If other screens like the settings screen work and the app under test does not work, then it means that the app developer have constrained the orientation.

-- Added as an answer as [Dan Hulme](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/12442/dan-hulme) suggested.